# Breaking up DSL IntegrationFlows

Tags: spring-integration

I've been playing around with Spring Integration (SI) DSL. I have a Rest service with the following Async Gateway defined :

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface Provision {
    @Async
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "provision.input")
    ListenableFuture<List<ResultDto>> provision(List<ItemsDto> stuff);
}
```

From the Line-by-line walk-through I have the follow example IntegrationFlow.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow provision() {
    return f -> f
            .split(ArrayList.class, List::toArray)
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .<ItemsDto, String>route(ItemsDto::getType, m -> m
                            .subFlowMapping("IPTV", sf -> sf
                                            .<ItemsDto, String>route(ItemsDto::getAction, m2 -> m2
                                                    .subFlowMapping("OPEN", sf2 -> sf2
                                                            .handle((p, h) -> iptvService.open((ItemsDto) p))))
                            )
            )
            .aggregate();
}
```

I have several layers of routing as you can see. I need to break things up a bit. I've tried several things which don't work (here I don't get a response...the thread doesn't wait):

```
@Bean(name = "routerInput")
private MessageChannel routerInput() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow provision() {
    return f -> f
            .split(ArrayList.class, List::toArray)
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .<ItemsDto, String>route(ItemsDto::getType, m ->
                            m.subFlowMapping("IPTV", sf -> sf.channel("routerInput"))
            )
            .aggregate();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow action() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("routerInput")
            .<ItemsDto, String>route(ItemsDto::getAction, m -> m
                    .subFlowMapping("OPEN", sf -> sf
                            .handle(p -> iptvService.open((ItemsDto) p.getPayload())))).get();
}
```

I'm obviously conceptually missing something :) Can someone perhaps assist with a "how to and why" opinion?

I have a list of items that need to be split, routed by "type", then routed by "action", and finally aggregated (containing response of handler). Each handled item needs to process in parallel.

Thanks in advance

Update:
From Artem's suggestion I removed all the async stuff. I trimmed it down to almost nothing...

```
@Bean(name = "routerInput")
private MessageChannel routerInput() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow provision() {
    return f -> f
            .split()
            .<ItemDto, String>route(ItemDto::getType, m ->
                    m.subFlowMapping("IPTV", sf -> sf.channel("routerInput")))
            .aggregate();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow action() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("routerInput")
            .<ItemDto, String>route(ItemDto::getAction, m -> m
                    .subFlowMapping("OPEN", sf -> sf
                            .handle((p, h) -> iptvService.open((ItemDto) p)))).get();
}
```

I got it to respond by changing

.handle(p ->

to this

.handle((p, h) ->

So it at least responds, but it does not aggregate the 3 test items that were split. Output consists of 1 item. Do I need to use a stream collect? Release policy? Shouldn't this be fine?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably simpler to use `channelMapping` rather than `subflowMapping` if you want to break it apart...

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow typeRoute() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(foo())
                .split()
                .<ItemsDto, String>route(ItemsDto::getType, m -> m
                        .channelMapping("foo", "channel1")
                        .channelMapping("bar", "channel2"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fooActionRoute() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(channel1())
                .<ItemsDto, String>route(ItemsDto::getAction, m -> m
                        .channelMapping("foo", "channel3")
                        .channelMapping("bar", "channel4"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow barActionRoute() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(channel1())
                .<ItemsDto, String>route(ItemsDto::getAction, m -> m
                        .channelMapping("foo", "channel5")
                        .channelMapping("bar", "channel6"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fooFooHandle() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(channel3())
                // handle
                .channel(aggChannel())
                .get();
    }
```

Create flows for the other options and aggregate each result:

```
    // fooBarHandle(), barFooHandle(), barBarHandle()


    @Bean IntegrationFlow agg() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(aggChannel())
                .aggregate()
                .get();
    }
```

The parallelism is handled by using `ExecutorChannel`s...

```
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel channel1() {
        return new ExecutorChannel(exec());
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel channel2() {
        return new ExecutorChannel(exec());
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel channel3() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel channel4() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel channel5() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel channel6() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel aggChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any big problems in your configuration and it really should work.

Want I don't like there is:

1. If you use `async` Gateway (`ListenableFuture<List<ResultDto>>`) you don't need `@Async` annotation there, because it will be already by the Gateway contract.
2. You don't need convert `List::toArray` if your `payload` is a `List` already. It is just enough to use `.split()` without params.

That's for the design style.

I'm not sure yet what's the problem there, but would you mind to make your whole flow **sync** and share with us here the `DEBUG` for the flow and point out where you see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Moved the aggregate to the "action" Bean and it worked.
Thanks for your patience :)